# How to send text to elements without id or value attribute using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

HTML:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" class="form-control m-2">
```

I am trying to send text to this through Selenium.
This is what I tried:

```java
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.form-control m-2[placeholder='Enter name']")).sendKeys("Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

`form-control` and `m-2` are two different classes.

The selector should be `input.form-control.m-2[placeholder='Enter name']`

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath to interact with the web Element.
The xpath will be -

```
//input[@placeholder='Enter name'][@type='text']
```

Use the following code -

```
WebElement inputName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter name'][@type='text']"));
inputName.sendKeys("Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the desired element with `placeholder` as **Enter name** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48369043/7429447):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder='Enter name']")).sendKeys("Test");
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter name']")).sendKeys("Test");
  ```

---

Ideally, to send a character sequence within the `<input>` element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder='Enter name']"))).sendKeys("Test");
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter name']"))).sendKeys("Test");
  ```